# Polygon inside ControlTemplate throws weird exception in Windows 8.1 app

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, controltemplate

I'm trying to have a way to reuse vectorial graphics throughout my apps.
My current approach is to have the graphics in UserControls, it works perfectly, but I don't like it.
I am trying to set the graphics via ControlTemplates, to this end I created an empty "BlankControl" which inherits from Control, and does absolutely nothing (for now).

The problem I'm having is when attempting to apply a ControlTemplate which contains a Polygon (all other contents work OK).

This is the problematic ControlTemplate:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="sharedcontrols:BlankControl" x:Key="controlTemplate">
                    <Viewbox>
                        <!--This file is compatible with Silverlight-->
                        <Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Name="Capa_1" Width="62.627" Height="63.636" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
                            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                            <Canvas.Resources/>
                            <!--Unknown tag: metadata-->
                            <!--Unknown tag: sodipodi:namedview-->
                            <Canvas Name="g3">
                                <Canvas Name="g5">
                                    <Canvas Name="g7">
                                        <Ellipse Fill="White" Width="55" Height="55" Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="5"/>
                                        <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path9" Fill="Blue" Data="M32.55 56.896c-13.674 0-24.795-11.123-24.795-24.795     c0-13.674 11.121-24.795 24.795-24.795s24.795 11.121 24.795 24.795C57.345 45.772 46.224 56.896 32.55 56.896z M32.55 3.101     c-15.994 0-29 13.006-29 29s13.006 29 29 29s29-13.006 29-29S48.544 3.101 32.55 3.101z"/>
                                            <Polygon Points="0,0 8,5, 0,10" Stroke="Black" Fill="Black" />

                                    </Canvas>
                                </Canvas>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Canvas>
                    </Viewbox>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

As I mentioned, if I remove the Polygon, it renders perfectly, but the polygon messes everything up, it throws the following exception:

```
Error       Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.PointCollection' to type 'System.Windows.Media.PointCollection'.
```

Really, really weird error, it seems to think the PointCollection I'm passing is of another type. Weirder even is that if I take the polygon from the ControlTemplate and place it anywhere else on the XAML, it renders OK, so the problem lies in the ControlTemplate.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: No solution, huh? Dang. This is the same in Windows UWP.

Comment: Disappointing, I was expecting UWP to be less crappy than WinRT.

Comment: That's because you think of them as two different things. Just one.

Comment: UWP is a superset of WinRT, so they are two different things. I had hoped they'd fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The message seems rather confusing, but so does your Points collection with all the commas and spaces and no decimal points (which in XAML are done using the period character - '.'). Typically you use a Path element and set its Data property to a geometry using the mini language markup used for vector graphics in xaml. This looks like an easy introduction: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/index/cc189041(v=vs.95).aspx

I wouldn't use `Polygon` elements directly. Ideally you would create a geometry in something like Blend or use it to convert one from say Illustrator file and paste the `Path` element into your XAML or even better - convert that to a font file that is better optimized for vector rendering.

In your case you could first try changing this...

```
0,0 8,5, 0,10
```

...to this

```
0,0 8,5 0,10
```

...to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: All those canvas, paths, and polygons were auto generated from a SVG file by Inkscape, it isn't really in my interest to change that. But, regardless, if I take the polygon outside the control template, it renders perfectly (and looks OK on an UserControl), so it shouldn't be an issue with the notation, or points. Ah! also, I tried with far simpler polygons, taken from examples online.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you should avoid using `Polygon` since `Path` should be sufficient to represent all geometries with a single `Data` string.

Comment: I don't really want to waste time converting to SVG to a Path, so I just take what Inkscape gives me. It's enough that SVG is, unbelievably, unsupported directly from XAML and I need to waste my time converting it. I tried changing what you suggested, removing the comma, did not work.